# One Time Login with htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a page I'd like to password protect: www.example.com/password-protected-page

I'll email my users their unique login details but I'd like theme to be only used once. So the very first login attempt will go through but when they try to login second time with their login details it won't let them in.

Is there any way I can do it with htpasswd? Or is there any other solution for this? I only have cPanel access for this hosting so modifying system files is not an option.

Comment: _“Is there any way I can do it with htpasswd?”_ - other than re-writing that file on every successful login? Probably not. And even that would only work, if you need to protect that one single resource only. As soon as it includes other resources (scripts, stylesheets, images) shown on that page, that also need to be protected, you’d probably run into “timing issues” with such an approach.

Comment: It is possible to use http basic authentication with other authorities than a ".htpasswd" style flat file. Instead you can use a database server for example or the PAM system common in LInux and Unix-like systems. That allows for a static ".htaccess" style file while still having the flexibility to create and use dynamic credentials. Certainly it would also be possible somehow permanently a ".htpasswd" style file, but that is not how things are meant to be used.